# How to access Secure file in a bash script

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

Using classic editor, i download a secure file via download securefile task. I am setting the reference name  to mySecureFile

[download secure file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybms6.png)
I have a bash script (not inline) where I am trying to use this secure file. This is the line in script
sf auth jwt grant --username $env:USERNAME_BAUQA --jwt-key-file $(Agent.TempDirectory)/mySecureFile.key --client-id $env:CLIENTID_BAUQA --instance-url $env:INSTANCE_URL_BAUQA

I am getting an error /home/vsts/work/1/s/auth_sf.sh: line 4: Agent.TempDirectory: command not found

Can you help

for script to access the secure file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your secure file task, the file name should be `server.key` **not** `mySecureFile.key`.

Besides the way `$AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY/server.key` in the script suggested by @Sanad Bhowmik.

You can also specify the `working directory` to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)` for the bash task, remember to remove the path for the file in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sf auth jwt grant --username $env:USERNAME_BAUQA --jwt-key-file server.key --client-id $env:CLIENTID_BAUQA --instance-url $env:INSTANCE_URL_BAUQA
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked now. The reason i was using mySecureFile was that I was assigning a reference name as mySecureFile in the download secure file task. can you tell me what the reference name is used for?

Comment: Glad to know it works! The reference name defined in the task will affect the output variable name `mySecureFile.secureFilePath` which you can used in the downstream tasks. If you `echo $(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)`, it will output the value like `/home/vsts/work/_temp/server.key`. If you can change the refernece name, the variable name will be changed too.

Comment: As it's resolved, could you please help to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sf auth jwt grant --username $env:USERNAME_BAUQA --jwt-key-file $AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY/mySecureFile.key --client-id $env:CLIENTID_BAUQA --instance-url $env:INSTANCE_URL_BAUQA
```

Comment: thanks but i am still getting this error:  Error (1): We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/_temp/mySecureFile.key'

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**